# Sizing background image CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to include a background image to my HTML `header` but it is not working the way I want it to.

Header:

```
<header class="background_image">

</header>
```

Currently the image only appears when my CSS is like so:

```
.background_image {
    background-image: url(image-path("header-bg.jpg"));
    height: 500px;
}
```

even then only a portion of the image is displayed

I've looked around and tried adding different combinations CSS properties such as:

```
background-size: auto;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

But each one of them has the imagine in a very thin line. At first I thought the image wasnt being loaded but I think only a sliver of it is being shown which I assume is the thin black line

Comment: I am still unclear what you are specifically asking for. Also you are not providing very much code, could you add the HTML as well?

Comment: @crazymatt The HTML isnt very important in this case but I can include it. It is simply a header tag

Comment: If your background image is being cut off either your CSS code is incorrect or you have another element that is overlapping. Just this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0zpbfsf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question, the < header > needs to have a height property to apply a visible background image.

Standards suggest it is not possible to auto adjust a selector to background image size just using CSS ... if that is what you are after.

That being said, depending on the rest of your layout ... check out this snippet (also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPEFn/2/)):

```css
div{
    background-image: url('http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.64%; /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
                /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What's up with the `image-path("header-bg.jpg")`?

That would be my guess. The proper formatting for an image in CSS is this:

`background-image: url(path/to/image.png);`

As seen in this example:

```
.background_image {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1200x500); // <-- This right here.
    height: 500px;
}
```

Also, if it's just that the header's cutting off your image, I highly recommend you take a look at the `background-size` non-numerical properties, such as `contain` and `cover`

Comment: image-path is a ruby on rails method